# Mutiple quantaties plotting in a chart in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, charts, multiple-columns

I am trying to plot a exam sheet of the students in excel. A target line that shows the maximum you can get in a test and all along. Then what a student have achieved in each of the questions. The image will have line and bar graph in one chart.

The bar graph shows how much a student scored in a test. With the two colors blue and orange representation scores in the two respective sections. His performance is plotted for the whole year. The dotted line graph represents the target of the students that they can reach if they score maximum. 
I use the following code function to draw one chart but when I try to include the second one, it overwrites the first one.

```
Sub CreateEmbeddedChartUsingShapesAddChart()

Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select chart inputs", Type:=8)
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=myRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns

myRange2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select chart inputs", Type:=8)
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=myRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns

ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.seriescollection.add) the series and then change its axis group to `xlSecondary`.

Comment: I am rookie at this. How should that look like exactly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It should go something like this:

```
Sub CreateEmbeddedChartUsingShapesAddChart()

  Dim MyRange1 As Range
  Set MyRange1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select line chart inputs", Type:=8)

  Dim MyChart As Chart
  Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine).Chart
  MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=MyRange1, PlotBy:=xlColumns

  Dim MyRange2 As Range
  Set MyRange2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select column chart inputs", Type:=8)

  With MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    If IsNumeric(MyRange2.Cells(1)) Then
      .Values = MyRange2
    Else
      .Values = MyRange2.Offset(1).Resize(MyRange2.Rows.Count - 1)
      .Name = "=" & MyRange2.Cells(1).Address(, , , True)
    End If
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
  End With

End Sub
```

Since the name of your procedure included "Embedded", I created an embedded chart, not the standalone chart sheet you ended up with.

Suggestion: Use more descriptive prompts for the input box commands. Also, if you're using Excel 2013 or later, use AddChart2, not AddChart.